# Lenovo G510 не работает

Tags: windows, железо, bios, windows-8, ноутбук

... Если быть точнее, после пары секунд после запуска выключает кулер, ничего на экран не выводит, лампочки горят. Иногда включается, работает две минуты и отрубается. С чем это может быть связано? Конфигурация оборудования нагружает BIOS?

Comment: неси в ремонт. софтом это не решить скорее всего

Answer (score 0):

Несколько возможных причин:

- отказ системы охлаждения
- отказ контроллера питания
- где-то коротит в цепи питания

Если оно прямо работает пару минут, то есть, Windows загружается, BIOS (UEFI) не виноват. Скорее всего, дело в железе.